# Setting density pixels programatically in Android not functioning correctly

Tags: android, xml, layout, screen, pixel-density

I have a list view which displays news items.

Each news item may / may not contain an image.

If it does contain an image, cool!

If it doesn't contain an image I set the image placeholder to invisible, and resize the frame layout it is contained inside.

I will show an image of my list view first:

[image]

As you can see the news item **with** the image is working as it should.
But the news item **without** the image is not !!.

In my XML Layout file I have the Blog/News Text View height set to 30dp.

```
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="30dp"
```

So, when no image exists I run the following code:

```
    if(no image is loaded)

        nimage.setVisibility(View.GONE); // set image placeholder to hidden
        // change frame layout height to 30dp (size of News/Blog)
        flayout1.getLayoutParams().height = (int)convertPixelsToDp(30, getContext()); 
        flayout1.requestLayout();
```

where my `convertPixelsToDp()` function is like this:

```
public static float convertPixelsToDp(float px, Context context){
    Resources resources = context.getResources();
    DisplayMetrics metrics = resources.getDisplayMetrics();
    float dp = px / (metrics.densityDpi / 160f);
    return dp;
}
```

This code should work,... I think. But clearly, as you can see above, the height is not set right. i.e - some of the TextView is cut off.

The thing is, when I run on a smaller screen, it works pretty well, but shouldn't it be screen size independent (using dp)... Maybe my conversion function is faulty?

Any help is hugely appreciated !

Comment: I don't understand why you don't use wrap_content as layout height of your TextView.

Comment: Thanks this fixed EVERYTHING!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use wrap_content as layout height of your TextView. This should fix your issue.